# Why a NSMutableArray objects are getting null values on sometimes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I'm using a UITableView and UITableViewCell in my project, I've customised the UITableViewCell properly, and in the TableView I'm displaying an Array of items, I'm assigning the values to that array in the below manner.

```
result= [[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:detail]]; [tableView1
     reloadData];//reloading table
```

It works properly, but after four or five times scrolling the TableView my app get crashed

> (SIGABRT)

, it shows the error

```
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 129 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

Comment: Could you please the exact line, where are you getting this error message?

Comment: You need to add your table view datasource code to question. That will help us to answer

Comment: That error says that you are trying to access object from out of array bounds, but where and how it's mystery from the info you are providing

Comment: you need to check your datasource array.

Comment: In the tableView's delegate method, cellforRowAtIndexPath , for a cell it shows null value

Comment: Thanks for your efforts dudes, I fixed this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reload the table view,It will call the delegate function bywhich all your cells will get reload.So before reloading do check whether your result array is having the data are not.It means you are trying to access the index of array beyond its limit(which is either released or not found). To get the exact place keep exception breakpoint and check.